# Query is resulting in 1 row with null values when id is not found

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

The exact query:

> SELECT
> `coupon_coupons`.`code`,
> `coupon_coupons`.`discountType` AS 'type',
> `coupon_coupons`.`discountAmount` AS 'amount',
> `coupon_coupons`.`discountApplied` AS 'applied',
> `coupon_coupons`.`description`,
> group_concat(`coupon_targetsku`.`sku` separator ';') AS 'targetsku' 
> FROM `coupon_coupons`
> LEFT JOIN `coupon_targetsku` ON `coupon_coupons`.`code` = `coupon_targetsku`.`code` 
> WHERE `coupon_coupons`.`code` = 'testCode'
>
> coupon_coupons.code = primary key
> coupon_targetsku.code = fk(coupon_coupons.code)

If the `coupon_coupons`.`code` is found in the database the query operates as expected, but when its not found the result set that is returned is one row with all NULL values. I'm guessing its something I'm doing wrong with the left join.

I would like this query to return zero rows if the code is not found.

I'm using mysql:
Server version 5.1.36-community-log
Protocol version: 10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good to use `group by` when using `group_concat()`

```
SELECT coupon_coupons.code,
coupon_coupons.discountType AS 'type',
coupon_coupons.discountAmount AS 'amount',
coupon_coupons.discountApplied AS 'applied',
coupon_coupons.description,
group_concat(coupon_targetsku.sku separator ';') AS 'targetsku' 
FROM coupon_coupons
JOIN coupon_targetsku ON coupon_coupons.code = coupon_targetsku.code 
WHERE coupon_coupons.code = 'testCode'
GROUP BY coupon_coupons.code
```

Comment: Yes when used with group by it worked well but yet... when there is no rows in the main table why 1 row with null is returned? is that how it has been designed to work?

Comment: my case was i am displaying one article and its details with tags. so a condition like " and article.id=5" will include only one row from the main table. when i give a wrong id then no rows in the main table exists but still the result is one row with null values... after using group by it worked well. yet why was it returning one row with null values?

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (coupon_coupons), even if there are no matches in the right table (coupon_targetsku).

For your situation a JOIN is what you want (Returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables)

Comment: Using simply the JOIN statement resulted in the same results.

Comment: oh, try taking out the group_concat. It is likely returning rows due to the concat returning a blank string. possibly replace with: group_concat(COALESCE(coupon_targetsku.sku, "") separator ';') AS 'targetsku'